# Строчная буква в названии привилегии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии

Название привилегии "правка вопросов и ответов" [написано с маленькой буквы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

> [image: правка вопросов и ответов]

Все остальные названия начинаются с прописной буквы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Буква капитализирована. Теперь всё выглядит единообразно.